# Problem with #ifndef and #pragma once

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, header

I want write the program with next struct

stdafx.h - contains some #define defenitions of program constants and #include of headers wich uses in all project.

frmMain.h - contatins code of Form1 also can Show form2 and uses some code from BckHeadr.h and some functions call that headers included in stdafx.h.

frmIniPrgs.h - contatins code of Form2 and uses some code from BckHeadr.h and some functions call that headers included in stdafx.h.

BckHeadr.h - contatins some definitions of functions and some functions call that headers included in stdafx.h.

I know what i must use #ifndef or #pragma once directives. But i can not decided this problem. I included in stdafx.h: frmIniPrgs.H, BckHeadr.h, frmMain.h. And use #ifndef in all modules. I uset it like this:

```
#ifndef MYMODULE_H
#define MYMODULE_H
//module code
#endif
```

There is next errors in my project (i have russian visual studio and text of errors is translate by google translate and may contain the errors, ScnIniPackages is my function in BckHeadr.h ):

```
BckHeadr.h (96): error C3861: PtrToStringChars: identifier not found 
BckHeadr.h (141): error C2065: vector: undeclared identifier 
BckHeadr.h (141): error C2062: type "int" is not required 
BckHeadr.h (141): error C2143: syntax error: no ";" before "(" 
BckHeadr.h (141): error C2447: (: missing function header (possibly using a formal list of old type) 
BckHeadr.h (169): error C2065: vector: undeclared identifier 
frmIniPrgs.h (119): error C2065: vector: undeclared identifier 
frmIniPrgs.h (122): error C3861: ScnIniPackages: identifier not found 
frmIniPrgs.h (121): error C2065: vector: undeclared identifier 
C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft SDKs \ Windows \ v6.0A \ include \ Wininet.h (381): error C2872: FILETIME: ambiguous symbol 
    be 'C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft SDKs \ Windows \ v6.0A \ include \ windef.h (377): _FILETIME FILETIME' 
    or 'c: \ windows \ microsoft.net \ framework \ v2.0.50727 \ mscorlib.dll: System:: Runtime:: InteropServices:: FILETIME'
```

Comment: You used the "linking" tag; are you encountering a compiler error or a linker error?

Comment: If you showed them to us, we could probably help.

Comment: Looks like the headers are not included properly. By any chance you used same MYMODULE_H for every file ?

Comment: In your `.cpp` file, did you by any chance include `BckHeadr.h` before `stdafx.h`?

Comment: for all files i have different MYMODULE_H. I have no code in .cpp files all code write in .h files. But i have thr frmIniPrgs.cpp in which write:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "frmIniPrgs.h"

Comment: Why are you putting your code in .h files ? What are you trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: i think it more easy way to achieve results

Comment: what do if there is no chance include BckHeadr.h before stdafx.h in my project. because BckHeadr.h use some libraries that included in stdafx.h or it is bad idea to include all libaries only in stdafx.h?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

This may solve some of the errors (if not all).

Answer (score 1):

You have to include proper STL headers.

```
#include <vector>
```

Also you can add namespace as

```
using namespace std;
```

Or use STL classes as

```
std::vector<>
```